# Convert linear and quadratic function to homographic matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, transformation

I have some equations I would like to convert to an homographic matrix in order to help me to apply some transformations to my images.
In the first case I have these two linear equations:
$$
    x' = A + Bx + Cy
$$
$$
    y' = D + Ex + Fy
$$
The homographic matrix must be an affine homographic matrix and I thought it was something like that
$$ H=\begin{pmatrix}B&C&A\\E&F&D\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
but when I try to have a scale different of 1 it does not work.

My other equations are of the forms:
$$
    x' = A + Bx + Cy + Dxx + Exy + Fyy
$$
$$
    y' = G + Hx + Iy + Jxx + Kxy + Lyy
$$

This time I would expect something like that
$$ H=\begin{pmatrix}B&C&A\\H&I&G\\..&..&1\end{pmatrix}$$
but I don't really know.
If someone can help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say that $H$ doesn’t work?

Comment: When I divide an image by 2 and I try to compute H, I have B = F = 2 while I would expect 0.5

Comment: Scaling via a change of coordinate system and scaling via modifying coordinates of points leads to different matrices that are inverses of each other. You need to decide which you’re doing.

Comment: OK.Now the only thing I want is to obtain the right homographic matrix for my linear AND quadratic transformation.

Comment: You can’t represent a quadratic transformation like that as a matrix multiplication. Each part of that transformation *can* be represented in matrix form as $\mathbf x^TQ\mathbf x$, but I can’t think of a good way to combine the two into a single matrix expression.

Comment: Humm ok. In my (poor?) understanding homography matrix contains unified transformation as rotation, translation, shear ... So I thought it could represent a quadratic function. What about the linear function ? Is there a way to nicely represent it ?